# Alertmanager repeat_interval and value

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I put $value in  label section of prometheus expression, alertmanager repeat_interval seems doesn't work when $value changed. For example, I set the threadhold of "CPU usage" as 80%. It will defanitly fire an alert when it reaches 81%, However it will fire another alert when the acutally cpu usage reaches 82%.
Any way to make repeat_interval work while value diffs?

Comment: Please add the Prometheus configuration (I didn't understand what "I put $value in label section of prometheus expression" means).

Comment: Hello Marcelo, thanks for your quick reply, please refer to below:

    - alert: cpu_usage
      annotations:
        description: ({{ $labels.instance }})
        summary: cpu_usage{{ $value }}%
      expr: |
        100 - floor((avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{service="node-exporter",mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)) > 80
      for: 0m
      labels:
        service: node
        value: '{{ $value }}'

Comment: I put the autual value in the lables and duration set to 0m(for: 0m). Current issue is: It will fire every alert after the value is beyond  threadhold 80, for example, when it reaches 81, it will definately accord with the rule and fire the alert, howevery, after it comes to 82, there will be another alert of the same alertname "cpu_usage".  repeat_interval seems doesn't work in alertmanage configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The Alertmanager creates a new alert when it finds an alerting rule with a different alert name OR different label values.

In your case, you set the following label:

```
labels:
  value: '{{ $value }}'
```

So, every time the value changes it creates a new alert.